# Is iMessages secure?

Tags: ios, messages

What security does iMessages provide or is it open and subject to the security of the connection used to send the messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iMessages are [transmitted with TLS (SSL) encryption](http://www.anandtech.com/show/4956/apple-ios-5-review/3), and the saved messages on your devices will be encrypted (like all other data), but the message contents themselves aren't encrypted. I'm not aware that Apple has publicly stated whether they store any iMessages on their servers, and how they might be encrypted.

Comment: Great linked article. Thanks for clearing this up.

Answer (score 0):

It is encrypted end to end better than SMS. I wouldn't call it secure, though since the code isn't peer-reviewed (AFAIK) nor does it pass the "dropped in a puddle" test to ensure you and only you have keys to decrypt the contents. (In other words, if you are not holding they keys, it's not very secure.)